# C Duality Expression

Tags: c

I have created a program in C which takes values of a,b and c from keyboard and show the "+value" and "-value" . But after when I give inputs it shows outputs such like "-1.#IND0" . Why this happens ? There are no compile errors...

Heres my code :

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
int main(void)
{
int a,b,c;
double x1,x2;
printf("Enter a ");
scanf("%d",&a);

printf("Enter b ");
scanf("%d",&b);

printf("Enter c ");
scanf("%d",&c);

x1 = ( (-1 * b) + sqrt(pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c)) ) /  2 * (float)a ;
x2 = ( (-1 * b) - sqrt(pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c)) ) /  2 * (float)a ;

printf("Plus Value %.5f\n",x1);
printf("Minus Value %.5f\n",x2);
}
```

Comment: You should check that the `scanf()`s succeed; I/O is tricky which is why they have return values. Also, what values for `a`, `b` and `c` give you the strange result?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but you don't need to multiply `b` with `-1` to change its sign, `-b` works just fine.

Comment: BTW `2 * (float)a` --> `(2 * a)`

Comment: You're assuming there are always two "valid" solutions; however, it is not the case. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quadratic_equation

Answer (score 3):

You need to check if `pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c)` is non-negative, otherwise you can't take the square root.

Also check `a` is not 0, since you are dividing by it.

Sanity checks are important to avoid unexpected behavior. Hope this helps!

Answer (score -1):

Your program is only valid for **a = 1**, because when **a > 1** take **a = 5** as example, the **sqrt(pow(b,2) - (4 * a * c))** will result in **sqrt(-ve)** value. That is why it is giving this output. This program is logically correct but not for all cases.

Comment: Umm why? Say `a=5`, `b = 5` and `c = 1`, you will have `sqrt(25 - 20) = sqrt(5)` which is valid. Even for `a <= 0` the `sqrt` expression could work. It depends on the values of `b` and `c` as well.

Comment: @StutiRastogi Yes you are correct, the whole thing is that sqrt() should not contain any negative value and for your example it is giving correct result.